# git clone throw an error : Could not resolve hostname Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

when I git clone form a remote repository , g[image]

I try all ways in google.But it still has the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the repository is there? and that you share with them your publick access key?

Comment: Use Google for "could not resolve hostname" and ask next question about this trouble on SU

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up necessary proxy settings.
This is commonly needed when you need to access git from your employers network.

in the .gitconfig file (for me located in the user folder) you can add proxy settings.

```
[http]
proxy = http://username:password@proxyserver:port
```

Remember, special characters in your username or password need to be url encoded (% notation, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

You can also set it though the command line with the following command

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxyserver:port
```

Replace `username`, `password`, `proxyserver` and `port` by their actual values.

Also make sure you have your ssh keys setup.
Github explains well how to do that: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer. I had make the repository private.

Comment: It was private and now you made it public? Remember when you make it public, anyone can see and copy your code. This is a solution only if you want that.

Comment: yes,it is true. As your answer,I don`t know the  `proxyserver:port`,How I get it?

Comment: You only need that if you are accessing the internet through a proxy. If you are just at home and you don't know what it is, then I don't think you need it. If you are at work, ask a colleague. Someone should know it.